# Transferring Data Between Scenes with U-Net

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a multiplayer FPS in Unity 3D with U-Net (I'm aware that u-net is deprecated) and I am interested in transferring an input string that is entered in my lobby scene to a sort of player name that I can use to show statistics during the round.

This is what I came up with:

```
public class NameSetter :MonoBehaviour
{
    private static string userName;
    public static string GetUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }
    public void SetUserName(string _usern)
    {
        userName = _usern;
    }
}
```

The SetUserName() function is bound to an OnValueChanged attribute of an input field.

Here is the relevant code from my Player class:

```
public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SyncVar]
    private string playername;

    public string PlayerName
    {
        get { return playername; }
        set { playername = value; }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        playername = NameSetter.GetUserName();
        _deaths = 0;
        killCount = 0;
        damageDealt = 0;
        ResetPlayer(false); // resets player health and plays a respawn effect
    }
}
```

When running the code on two separate clients the usernames both end up being the username that the host entered.

I have also tried setting the username on a different script in an OnStartClient method in this case, on the host the host's username appeared twice and on the client it appeared to work fine.(This is for two players, when a third joins everything goes haywire :P)

Here is the relevant code:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Player))]
public class PlayerSetup : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public override void OnStartClient()
    {
        base.OnStartClient();

        string netId = GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().netId.ToString();
        Player curr = GetComponent<Player>();
        curr.PlayerName = NameSetter.GetUserName();
        GameManager.AddPlayer(netId, curr);
        // The GameManager refers to a dictionary of players and id's that is used to keep track of all 
        // the players
    }
```

I assume these problems have something to do with the field being static, However I can't seem to find a better alternative for transferring the variable between my lobby scene and my online scene, especially since the alternative needs to be dynamic. Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: Put it on an empty gameObject in your lobby scene and mark it `DontDestroyOnLoad`

Comment: Can you explain why you've made your username field and GetUserName method static?

Comment: @Josh that would create an object for each client and then when they don't get destroyed there'll be an object for each client, wouldn't that hurt performance?

Comment: @ErikOverflow as i understand it, static objects don't get deleted by unity when transitioning between scenes but I might be wrong since I'm fairly new to unity

Comment: @barbecu that is no true. Static methods and fields are accessible at the Class-level, rather than the instance level (All player classes would share the same static field/method). If you want data to persist between scenes, use DontDestroyOnLoad.

Comment: @barbecu It would only create a new one in the next scene if you have a copy of that gameObject in both scenes. Unfortunately Unity requires some anti-patterns to get certain things right. In this case, it would be the `singleton` pattern. Your gameObject should have a script that holds all these clients, and that "master" gameObject should follow the singleton pattern, meaning it holds a static reference to itself. In the constructor, check if this reference is null. If it is, finish construction. If not, you already have one and can cancel.

Comment: @Josh The Singleton pattern worked! Thanks for the help!